# Get URL of requesting website in WEB API 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I need to get URL of requesting web site in My WEB API 2. I need to do this because of security. I want to response to the request which are coming from the  URLs that are registered on my server.

In Web API I have used

1. Owin
2. OAuth 2.0

So far I have tried to get it from owin context and http context but no one gives URL. I am able to get IP address of the requesting web site.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Origin` header of the request.

Also I'd recommend to look at [CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) and not reinvent the wheel. You'll be able to specify valid request origins for your api.